Inconsistent catkin build result in same dockerfile
I write a dockerfile and use docker compose build
to setup container and catkin build the ros workspace. However, with same dockerfile, the building can fail in 1 computer and succeed in another computer. The failing reason is catkin can not find my_message.h while I already add dependencies in CMakeList and package.xml.
It seems strange to me since docker containers supposed to be strictly same.

This looks like a software configuration issue, not a robotics Q&A question.

Without reading your Dockerfile, I can only speculate about your exact issue. Still, there are a few plausible reasons that could explain this discrepancy.
Base Image Update - Depending on when you built the image on each computer, the base image (e.g., FROM ubuntu:24.04) may have been updated between the two builds. If you were building your image for the first time on the second computer, it would pull the latest base image from the repository, potentially bringing in changes relative to the first build.
Git Clone Version - Although it's not necessarily the best practice, it can be useful to clone dependencies directly from GitHub during the Docker build so that Docker can handle the cloned repo's dependencies. If your Dockerfile specified the version to be cloned using a branch name, rather than a tag name, the two different builds may have pulled different commits of the cloned repository.
Dependency Versioning - Similar to the other cases, if your Dockerfile uses something like apt-get install or pip to install dependencies, your build may install different versions on different machines if the Dockerfile doesn't explicitly specify versions for all mentioned dependencies.
